# GIT output shown as error in team build 2013

Tags: git, powershell, tfs

### Background

We have a team build 2013 server running against our GIT repository hosted on TFS 2013 update 4. In this build we want to tag our sources at the end of the build with the build number from that build.

### Question

I have got the described scenario working. I wrote a powershell script that runs as a post step of the build.

```
git -C $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY tag -a ($env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER.Split("_")[1]) -m "$env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER"
git -C $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY push origin master --tags
```

The command is succesful, but my Build is shown as yellow in the browser. This is happening because GIT is writing output as error. Which is nuts, because it's just information about something that the tool has done for me.

Is there any way to prevent GIT from outputting normal output as error in powershell/teambuild 2013?

Comment: Use the `-q` flag on the `push` command? Redirect the output away? (What output exactly is being sent as an error? Do you mean standard error? Do you mean teambuild is flagging the content?)

Comment: If you add a line `exit 0` at the end of your script, does that solve your problem?

Comment: Im guessing you're using posh-git for that matter....? anyway, have you tried redirecting the output of your git command such as "$output=git -c $Env:TF_B........."  or "<command> 2&>1"?

Comment: I tried to redirect the output, doesn't work. The exit 0 options sounds like it could work. Going to try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a PowerShell script you could redirect the output from error to standard like this:

```
git -C $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY tag -a 2>&1 | Write-Host($env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER.Split("_")[1]) -m "$env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER"
git -C $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY push origin master --tags 2>&1 | Write-Host
```